# Font fallback on text applied with custom font attributes on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, multilingual, nsattributedstring, uifont, typeface

I use custom font family "Aller Typo" in our app with a feature supporting multi-lingual text editing (UITextView) and use -

"AllerTypo-Light" for plain text (no type face)

**"AllerTypo-Regular" for bold.**

"AllerTypo-LightItalic" for italic.

**"AllerTypo-Italic" for bold italic.**

**The problem** is when I apply the font on texts (glyphs) not supported in this font family, it presumably fallback to a font (e.g. "Helvetica" family for Russian text) reapplying the client font face traits but unaware of the fact that I use "AllerTypo-Regular" version for it's **bold**-ness. Please help me resolve this.

Please see below code snippet for what I talked about above.

```
// Apply current theme on default attributes (like font, text color)
NSMutableAttributedString *updatedAttribText = [attribText mutableCopy];

[updatedAttribText beginEditing];
[attribText enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, attribText.length)
                               options:0
                            usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

                                // Check for font attributes
                                UIFont *textRunfont = [attrs objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
                                NSMutableDictionary *updatedAttribs = [attrs mutableCopy];

                                [updatedAttribs updateAttributesWithTextStyle:textRunfont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits action:YES fontFamily:@"Aller Typo"];

                                // Check for default text color now
                                UIColor *textRunColor = [attrs objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

                                if ([textRunColor isEqual:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]]) {
                                    UIColor *defaultTextColor = [[QGThemeHelper currentTheme] uiTextViewTextColor];

                                    [updatedAttribs setValue:defaultTextColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
                                }

                                [updatedAttribText setAttributes:updatedAttribs range:range];
                            }];

[updatedAttribText endEditing];
```

NSMutableDictionary category method, used above, to update text attributes.

```
- (void)updateAttributesWithTextStyle:(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits)updateStyleTraits action:(BOOL)addAction fontFamily:(NSString *)familyName
{
    UIFont *currentFont = [self objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits updatedTraits = 0;

    // Fetch existing traits and then apply the text style
    if (!addAction) {   // Remove
        updatedTraits = ([currentFont qg_textStyleTraits] & ~updateStyleTraits);
    }
    else {  // Apply
        updatedTraits = ([currentFont qg_textStyleTraits] | updateStyleTraits);
    }

    // Appropriate font from the family with mentioned traits (bold, italic, bold italic).
    NSString *updatedFontName = [UIFont qg_fontNameFromFamily:familyName withTextStyleTraits:updatedTraits];
    UIFont *updatedFont = [UIFont fontWithName:updatedFontName size:currentFont.pointSize];

    [self setObject:updatedFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
}
```

In other words, is there any way I can communicate to fallback system about my intentions (font customization)? The italic feature works fine because the "AllerTypo-Italic" font carries that trait with it and system reapplies that during fallback.

Additional note - The text content source (attributed text) is encoded HTML tags stored in CoreData which is sync'd back to our web app as well.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `UIFontDescriptorCascadeListAttribute`.

In order to achieve that, you might need to create `UIFont` with `-[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:size:]`, and for the descriptor, you need to set attribute `UIFontDescriptorCascadeListAttribute` with the fonts you want to fall back to.